# PHP taking extra time when making another connection to MySQL for logging purposes

Tags: php, mysql

I have various PHP scripts which run all day via cron jobs and as more users use my application, the cron jobs are taking longer. These jobs started taking twice as long when I moved from file logging to database logging because (I believe) the logging function takes time to make a new connection to the database - about one second each.

My structure is as follows. The scripts run by cron jobs look like this:

```
<?php
require("db-helper-class.php");
require("action-class.php");

$con = new DB();
$action = new ActionClass($con);

$action->method_1();
```

The "Action Classes" look like this:

```
<?php 
include "logging-functions.php";

class ActionClass {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(DB $pdo) {
        //connect to database
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    public function method_1() {
        //do stuff like a database action
        $sql = "...";
        $this->db->$query($sql)

        //log result        
        logSomething($vars);

        //do another database action
        $sql = "...";
        $this->db->$query($sql)

        //log result        
        logSomething($vars);

    }
...
```

And the "logging-functions.php" looks like this:

```
<?php 
require_once("db-helper-class.php");

function logSomething($input) {
    $logDBcon = new DB();
    $sql = "...";
    $logDBcon->query($sql);
    ...
}
```

So as you can see, when logging, multiple new connections are happening. I have 2 main questions:

1. Am I right in saying that my extra logging connections are a slow point because of the new connection.
2. Would I be right in saying that I will lose the `lastInsertId()` if I included the logging in the original connection?
3. And to sneak in a third question, is this design even best practice?

Comment: "And to sneak in a third question, is this design even best practice?" This question is off topic for Stackoverflow. Question should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com .. But a Singleton database class should be a much better design because you reuse the class and so you reuse the MySQL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes and NO. Making a connection itself, sure, takes time but that's so insignificant so you shouldn't even bother. What makes your application slow would be if you've got really slow queries.
2. The question is not clear. If you run get insert id command against a connection it will return you last inserted id for that connection. Read: those 2 connections are isolated from each other.
3. I'd say no since you endangered to open/close (btw, you should be mindful about closing connections) a ton of connections whenever you call that logging method. I'd open up a connection once and shut that down as soon as the program is finished.

To sneak a side-note: to contemplate about best practices you should create a new question on SO since those kind of questions are usually bloated. So this question is, indeed, sneaky.